# What is the best way to returning time of calculation?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the best way to returning time of calculation of some method? For example I have a multiplty method and the expexted result is one integer value, but what should I do if my user wants to get both (result and time) or only int result? I think that structure isn't the best way.

Comment: Stop Watch :https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjXlvXcudfNAhUB6RQKHRJACg8QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.diagnostics.stopwatch(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFEnlxoU3r1ptfeaVQeF0EU7wd2xg&bvm=bv.126130881,d.bGs&cad=rja

Comment: This makes no sense IMO. Why should a user care about some milliseconds a multiply-operation takes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement it with a combination of [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class and an [output parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) as follows:

```
public int Multiply(int x, int y, out int elapsedMilliseconds) 
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    int result = x * y;

    stopWatch.Stop();

    elapsedMilliseconds = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    return result;
}

// You can also provide this overload to avoid giving the output parameter
// to receive the elapsed time if it's not required at all:
public int Multiply(int x, int y) 
{
    int elapsedMilliseconds;

    return Multiply(x, y, out elapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

*BTW, I suspect that using a stopwatch for this case is pointless. It might make sense if you use it in time-consuming tasks...*

Answer (score 0):

A few simple approaches to get the juices flowing. Not sure how you want this stuff to be used.

```
public class Evaluate
{
    public Stopwatch Timer { get; private set; }

    public Evaluate()
    {
        this.Timer = new Stopwatch();
    }

    public static long Elapsed(Action expression)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        expression();
        return timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    public static T ElapsedWithReturn<T>(Func<T> expression, ref long elapsed)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        T result = expression();
        elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        return result;
    }

    public T IncrementTimer<T>(Func<T> expression)
    {
        this.Timer.Start();
        T result = expression();
        this.Timer.Stop();
        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static int Multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        int result = x * y;
        return result;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int result;
        long elapsed;

        // evaluate a bunch of code using static evaluate function.
        elapsed = Evaluate.Elapsed(() =>
        {
            result = Multiply(1, 2);
            result = Multiply(2, 3);
            result = Multiply(3, 4);
        });

        // evaluate with specific return value, setting elapsed by reference
        result = Evaluate.ElapsedWithReturn(() => Multiply(1, 2), ref elapsed);

        // evaluate with specific return value, getting elapsed over time from class
        Evaluate evaluate = new Evaluate();
        result = evaluate.IncrementTimer(() => Multiply(1, 2));
        result = evaluate.IncrementTimer(() => Multiply(2, 3));
        elapsed = evaluate.Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```